# "bad input" after executing any git command

Tags: python, bash, git, macos

Yesterday I just installed [this script](https://github.com/nicc777/macaws-codecommit-pwdel) on my Macbook because I was having issues with the git credentials being stored in the keychain and after these expired [I was getting error 403](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html#setting-up-https-unixes-credential-helper). I found that script that claims to periodically check for those credentials and delete them to avoid that kind of problems.

The problem is that every time I do any git command, my console says:

```
$ git pull
bad input: SgSNnX3
Already up to date.
```

As we can see, it does the git operation without problems but seems like something else is happening before executing the git command. I already uninstalled the script mentioned earlier but the annoying message still showing up.

Does anyone know what can I do to stop that message?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this?

Answer (score -1):

You can open ~/.gitconfig from any terminal you have and remove the cache and wincred helpers.

Comment: It's not *totally* obvious to me if/how this helps.  In particular, I wonder if `~/.gitconfig` can be guaranteed to be the culprit (or if it might be useful to use `git config` for global messups.